# SQL Database project without existing database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am busy developing a new web app that obviously needs a database. I have decided to go for SQL Server. I would like to design the database within Visual Studio by creating a SQL Database Project. Thing is most of the references I've seen on the internet have an existing database that they import into the project.

Is there a way to create a database project with a blank database and create the tables, procs, etc. in the Visual Studio project?

Comment: You can create logical database diagram using tools like `ERWIN` or `pgModeler(open source for postgres)`

Comment: If you are going for a database first approach then it would be ideal to do it in SSMS or Azure Data Studio.  Otherwise (code first), your entities will auto-create the database. In both cases, you can use a database project to maintain the schema and master data in version control (Git or TFS).